# Return "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT" when calling nodejs api with nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, devops, nginx-config, aws-application-load-balancer

I have setup node api project in ec2. AWS architecture is something looks like as shown below

> Api.com > route53 > application load balancer > nginx > node
> application serve through pm2.

**Test case and issue I am facing:**

1. When I call api with postman, I get proper response with 200 status. In pm2 logs, I can get "/healthcheck". If I continue to hit api without stoping it will return proper response.
2. But if I stop calling api, and try after 1 minute or few seconds, I get "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 100.88.99.197:443". In api pm2 logs, I cannot get "/healthcheck". Pm2 also show process running without error. And if I continue to hit again and again, api will again start after few seconds.

**Node api (without database):**

```
app.get('/healthcheck', async function (req, res) {
    console.log("/healthcheck");
    res.send()
})
```

May be issue is with nginx keepalive or any other config settings.
**I request your help on this.**